# action or actionListener not fired when using pattern "hh:mm a" in Prime faces calendar p:calendar

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, date-format, datetime-conversion

I need to use prime faces calendar to fill time **ONLY** as the following :

```
<h:body>
   <h:form>
      <p:calendar pattern="hh:mm a" value="#{bean.startTime}"/>
      <p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{bean.saveAppointment}" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

But the `saveAppointment` method not fired at all. and without any Exception.

After tracing the issue I have concluded that the issue from the date conversion that primefaces uses under the cover.That is because when I omit `a` from the pattern i.e.(the pattern become `pattern="hh:mm"`).
Then the action fired normally without any issue.

**Note** Primefaces version is 6

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround by using `pattern="HH:mm"` and the capital H will make the hours 0-23 based.

Answer (score -1):

Check option: timeOnly="true".

Comment: It is irrelevant. it is relevant only to how you want to show the calendar popup date or time only

Comment: Ok, probably is irrelevant in this issue. However I'm not sure what do you want to achieve. Expected value is eg. '09:33 AM' and in this case value is correct (try to enter '09:33 AM') and you can call your action, in other case (for value in format hh:mm) validation on this input is incorrect and this is reason that action wasn't execute. Error of validation is not exception is normal behavior if you add p:messages you propably will look error message.

Comment: Try to apply the above simple example and you will see how the action not fired